# dompdf: Cannot find any examples?

Tags: php, dompdf

Just discovered dompdf on https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
But I cannot find any examples how to implement this library? I just need a simple example how to make a pdf out of an html file. Nothing more.

Could anyone help me to give me a starting point?

Kind regards!

Comment: Basic usage instructions are on the page you cited and in the [wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage). The [next release](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/develop) will have a bit more info in the README.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before but a quick bit of searching for "dompdf examples" finds something similar to the following code sample quite often

```
<?php
    $html = '<h1>Hello</h1>'; // Can use file_get_contents() to get a full html file
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

However, I suggest using [phpwkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf). This is a bit more complicated to setup (I won't go into it here) but the explanations online are very good and the resultant PDF beats anything else I've found. You must be able to install binaries ([wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)) on the server though so if you are using shared hosting it's not usually an option.

Comment: exactly, in my case i have to worked on a shared host, so i have no access. thats why im looking for a solution with dompdf. thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I have found others where the dompdf-file is required. However I had issues with the require_once directive, it doesnt work to include the php file which holds the dompdf functions. It shows no error, nothing, so I gave up on trying this stuff.

I really dont know why its so complicated to create a pdf out of a simple html, this should be a common task, no?